# iOS : Get currently downloading bytes with ASIHttpRequest

Tags: ios, download, mpmovieplayercontroller, asihttprequest, nsdata

I am downloading a video file using ASIHttpRequest, I am able to get the downloaded file in the destination path after completion of the download. But as my requirement, I want to play the currently downloaded video using `MPMoviePlayerController`, How do I get currently downloaded bytes in `NSData` format to play it with `MPMoviePlayerController`?

I.e. if video is of 200mb, and I'd already downloaded 50mb then while downloading remaining video I can also able to play the 50mb video.

Here's my code that downloading a file.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTag:tag];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:60.f];
[request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];

[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressView];

[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];

//    These delgates won't working
//    [request setDidReceiveResponseHeadersSelector:<#(SEL)#>]
//    [request setDidStartSelector:<#(SEL)#>]

[request setDownloadDestinationPath:downloadPath];
[request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
[request startAsynchronous];

//this will not call because I set UIProgressView to show downloading progress, to call it I need to set `self`
-(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes
```

Any luck? Other solution?

Comment: Just an FYI if you were not aware: ASIHTTPRequest is not longer actively developed/maintained (and hasn't been for over a year). You may want to consider using an alternative

Comment: @bengoesboom, Yes! I'm aware of that. But that is already implemented, and I'd to make changes!

Comment: @bengoesboom, after you suggestion, I tried with AFNetworking, and the same problem with that too. [Here's](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1454) I've posted  issue on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a whole API for streaming video over HTTP.  Check out all the details at https://developer.apple.com/streaming/.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm able to play video with an URL, I am only concern to play the video part which I've already downloaded.